# How to automate adding existing project files and directory into visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have an existing project which I want to build in `Visual studio 2010`. The project contains more than 200 folders and sub-folders. So, to add all the project files, I need to create a `new filter` and go on adding the source and header files. so, it takes me a lot of time. Pleas help me how can i automate or simplify this process.

See below:-

```
Main folder->|Sub Folder1->20 Folders (Each folder contains 5 files(let say) and does include some more flders)
             |Sub Folder2->10 Folders (same as above)
              ....
              ....
```

I have created visual studio project with the name as `Main Folder`, then added "New Filter" as `Sub Folder1` and `Sub Folder2` and so on. This effort takes lots of time. Please help me.

Comment: Today the only way to go is to write an IDE addin, but I think in VS2010 you could still record an IDE macro while adding a single file, then inspect and generalize the code. Have you tried it?

Comment: .vcproj is a text file, with a pretty obvious structure. It shouldn't be too difficult to write a script that generates a piece of text in the correct format, then simply copy/paste that text into the project file.

Answer (score 0):

I use VBScript with standard COM component `Microsoft.XMLDOM` to reorganize project tree structure for my needs (I can't share it, sorry). But I'd prefer using Python for such purpose (if possible) because it contains standard package `xml.etree.ElementTree` and because I like Python better than VBScript. :)

[This article may be useful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx) (there are VBS examples).
[This is a Python script](https://gist.github.com/avakar/5075992) that I quickly googled and it looks very close to your requirements.